# Receiving animated image in WhatsApp, what is this?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, images

Recently my friend send me this animated image on WhatsApp.

[Link to the animated image](http://screencast.com/t/o37CAhRHm24)

I was shocked to see an animated GIF in WhatsApp. When I shared to Facebook, it was shared just like a static image, and when I save it to my Mac via http://web.whatsapp.com, it was saved with extension of MP4.

When I shared a GIF from the web, it doesn't animate in WhatsApp. Also, when I shared a video, it also doesn't play like this image.

I am not able to figure it out what's unique with this.

Comment: We have a sophisticated membership who have a tendancy not to click rando links like this here.

Comment: @wbogacz what does it mean ?

Comment: Means one does not simply click random links (like yours to the animated image)

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: All WhatsApp versions now have GIF support.

---

The latest version of WhatsApp supports GIF images.

If you're on Android and Play Store shows that your WhatsApp is up-to-date, then download the beta version by joining [the official WhatsApp beta program](https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.whatsapp).